# Django Admin only showing one record

Tags: django, django-admin

I just did a migration and now my Django Admin for a specific model is only showing 1 record on the first page, all other pages are empty, even though it says there are 40000+ records across 4000+ pages (which there should be - they are in the database). What is happening here? This is on Django 3.0 .

[image]

Comment: probably the problem is with your .__str__() method in your model.It's returning a field that it's null.check it !

Comment: @tohidsadeghian very close, see my answer below. It was another field that was non-nullable but was empty nonetheless due to a bad data migration.

Answer (score 0):

Leaving this here in case someone runs into the same problem in the future: I applied a bad data migration that introduced a discrepancy between settings of a column in my database and in my Django Model. The column was nullable in my database and so a lot of rows were not filled-in, while in the Model it had `null=False`.

Apparently Django craps out and just doesn't show anything when it exepcts a value in a non-nullable field but the database doesn't provide one.

Filling in all missing values in my database and then setting the colum to non-nullable so that it is inline with the Model fixed it.